# Movement of turtles between nodes following the shortest path

Tags: location, netlogo, shortest-path, path-finding

I am trying to move my citizens from one node (slocation) to another node (new-location) calculating the shortest path.
I could only calculate the distance from slocation to new-location using set total-expected-path [distance [slocation] of myself] of new-location.

However, I am pretty sure that the following line after to set total-expected-path are not correct. I got the following error: this code can't be run by a turtle, only a link error while node 35 running LINK-LENGTH

How can I define this distance calculate in the total-expected-path as the minimum between nodes using the link connection between nodes?
and after that, how can I move the turtles following this short path?[image]
    to go
    set-timekeeper
    ask citizens
    [find-day-activities]
    end

```
to set-timekeeper
tick 
let counter ticks 
if (counter = 2) 
[set timekeeper 2]
end

to find-day-activities
if (timekeeper = 2) 
[Do_7AM_9AM]
end

to Do_7AM_9AM
if (sex = 0 and age = 1 and employment = 0 and household-size = 0 [move-work]
end

to move-work
to move-work
set slocation min-one-of nodes [distance myself]
let new-location min-one-of nodes [distance one-of workbuildings]
let llocation one-of [link-neighbors with-min [link-length]] of new-location
move-to llocation
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use the `nw` extension to take advantage of the `nw:turtles-on-path-to` or `nw:turtles-on-weighted-path-to` primitives. With these extensions and variables:

```
extensions [nw]
breed [ nodes node ]
breed [ walkers walker ]
links-own [ weight ]
```

and this setup:

```
to setup-example
  ca
  let xs [ 10 -5 -5 -5 -5 2 ]
  let ys [ 0 0 3 6 9 9 ]
  ( foreach xs ys [
    [ x y ] ->
    ask patch x y [
      sprout-nodes 1 [
        set shape "circle"
        set color white
        set size 2.5
      ]
    ]
  ])
  let ind ( range 0 4 )
  foreach ind [
    i ->
    let x item i xs
    let y item i ys
    let xn item ( i + 1 ) xs
    let yn item ( i + 1 ) ys
    ask nodes-on patch x y [
      create-links-with nodes-on patch xn yn
    ]
  ]
  while [ any? nodes with [ count my-links < 2 ] ] [
    ask one-of nodes with [ count my-links < 2 ] [
      let linkable min-one-of other nodes with [ count my-links < 2 ] [distance myself]
      if linkable != nobody [
        create-link-with linkable
      ]
    ] 
  ]
  ask nodes-on patch -5 0 [ set color green ]
  ask nodes-on patch 2 9 [ set color red ]  
end
```

This creates a loop network- pretend that the green is the start node and the red is the destination.

[image]

Now, using `nw:turtles-on-path-to` you can identify the nodes in the path that gets to the destination by the fewest links:

```
to fewest-links
  let start one-of nodes-on patch -5 0
  let target one-of nodes-on patch 2 9

  let path nobody 
  ask start [
    set color green
    set path but-first nw:turtles-on-path-to target
    ask turtle-set path [ set color yellow ]
    ask target [ set color red ]
  ]  
end
```

[image]

Or, using `link-length` as the `weight` variable in `nw:turtles-on-weighted-path-to`, you can get the shortest distance:

```
to shortest-distance
  let start one-of nodes-on patch -5 0
  let target one-of nodes-on patch 2 9
  ask links [ 
    set weight link-length
  ]
  let path nobody 
  ask start [
    set color green
    set path but-first nw:turtles-on-weighted-path-to target weight
    ask turtle-set path [ set color yellow ]
    ask target [ set color red ]
  ]  
end
```

[image]

To actually have your people move along a particular path, you can use a combination of the path identifying code above and `foreach`. Example setup for that:

```
to setup
  ca
  create-nodes 10 [ 
    set shape "circle" 
    set color white 
    set size 2.5
  ]
  layout-circle nodes 10
  while [ any? nodes with [ count my-links < 2 ] ] [
    ask one-of nodes with [ count my-links < 2 ] [
      let linkable min-one-of other nodes with [ count my-links < 2 ] [distance myself]
      if linkable != nobody [
        create-link-with linkable
      ]
    ] 
  ]
  ask one-of nodes [ 
   set color green + 1
   hatch-walkers 1 [
      set color blue
      set size 1.5
    ]
  ] 
  reset-ticks
end
```

And the movement itself:

```
to go
  ask walkers [
    ; Randomly choose a target node to walk to
    let target one-of nodes with [ color = white ]
    if target != nobody [
      ; Remember the starting node
      let current one-of nodes-here 
      ; Define a path variable from the current node- take all but
      ; the first item (as first item is current node)
      let path nobody
      ask links [ set weight link-length ]
      ask current [ 
        set path but-first nw:turtles-on-weighted-path-to target weight
      ]
      ; Indicate the end node
      ask last path [ 
        set color red
        set size 2.5
      ]
      ; Move along the path node-to-node 
      foreach path [
        next-target ->
        face next-target
        move-to next-target
        wait 0.25
        ask next-target [
        set color yellow
        ]
      ]
    ]
    wait 1
    ; Reset
    ask nodes [ set color white ]
    ask one-of nodes-here [ set color green ]
  ]
end
```

[image]